# Rails 5 model Initialise wrong number of arguments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi there im trying to create a model for a runescape item. Using there api and httparty. Im having a number of issues. But this one is regarding the use of overriding the initialize method saying it has the wrong number of arguments.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  require 'json'
  include HTTParty


  base_uri 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/'


  attr_accessor :name, :description, :price, :icon_url


  def initialize(name, description, price, icon_url)
    super
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.price = price
    self.icon_url = icon_url
  end


  def self.find(name)
    response = get("/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=#{name}")
    if response.success?
      parsed = JSON.parse(response)
      self.new(
      parsed["item"]["name"],
      parsed["item"]["description"],
      parsed["item"]["current"]["price"],
      parsed["item"]["icon_large"]
      )
    else
      # this just raises the net/http response that was raised
      raise response.response
    end
  end
end
```

So in rails console i run the following command to test it:

item_test = Item.find("227")

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0..1)
    from /Users/jacksharville/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/core.rb:312:in `initialize'
    from /Users/jacksharville/Desktop/OSCRUDDY/app/models/item.rb:13:in `initialize'
    from /Users/jacksharville/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:65:in `new'
```

But the initialize takes 4 arguments. When reduce it to one then it says it requires 4. Which leaves me very confused.

Im not even sure that overriding the base initialise is the way forward to do something like this. So if you have a better idea please let me know i'm new to this.

In conclusion my question is why is my object not being created correctly? Secondly is this the right approach for creating the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see here is that you are trying to mixin `HTTParty` with an `ActiveRecord` subclass, when really you should have two separate classes.  The Item class should be responsible for interfacing with your database.  You should create another class, i.e. `ItemResource` with `Httparty`, which will have the responsibility of connecting to the Runescape resource and respond with a response.  You should use this to grab the data from the resource, and create an `Item` record with that data. [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

One thing to keep in mind is that you should almost never be redefining `initialize` for any models that inherit from `ApplicationRecord`. Checkout the [API](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActiveRecord%2FBase%3Ainitialize)

EDIT
This code should get you relatively close

```
#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord; end

#app/models/item_resource.rb | app/resources/item_resource.rb or something similar
require 'json'
class ItemResource
  include HTTParty

  self.base_uri 'http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/'

  def find name
    response = get("/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=#{name}")

    if response.success?
      parsed = JSON.parse(response)
      Item.new(
        name: parsed["item"]["name"],
        description: parsed["item"]["description"],
        price: parsed["item"]["current"]["price"],
        icon_large: parsed["item"]["icon_large"]
      )
    else
      raise response.response
    end
  end
end

#somewhere else

item = ItemResource.find 'Elysian Spirit Shield'
if item.save
  #do stuff
else
  #handle failure
end
```

Comment: To be honest i dont really require to save this data to a database at all. But all i need to do is run some checks agains the api and do some maths against it. So removing that solved the issue indirectly answered my question thanks !

Comment: Let me know if you have anything else concerning ruby or osrs that I can help with :)